# What is the difference between Partially Observable and Incomplete information in Game theory

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game

In reference to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220835260_An_Extension_of_Bayesian_Game_Approximation_to_Partially_Observable_Stochastic_Games_with_Competition_and_Cooperation) paper that discusses Partially Observable Stochastic Game, it also mentions of Bayesian Game which is characterized by incomplete information. Rather then pointing out the differnce between the meaning of partially observable vs incomplete, the paper just merely discusses Bayesian games briefly.

I am confused about the nature of "partially observable", it means that the information is incomplete as we cant observe it fully so it is indeed Bayesian Game in nature.

I want to understand what is the difference between the two.